# dividing floats and rounding to int in java

Tags: java, floating-point

The following is from the exerpt taken from comb sort. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_sort
I want to divide gap with shrink in floating point arithmatic and then round the result to the int value. How shall i do that ?

```
    int gap = array.length - 1;
    double shrink = 1.3f;
```

I tried to do below

```
gap = Math.floor(((double) gap) / shrink);
```

but compiler complains that cannot convert from double to int.

If i do that below probably it would truncate but not round.

```
 gap =(int) Math.floor(((double) gap) / shrink);
```

Is there any function which divides the int with doubles in floating point arithmatic and round the result to the int. How shall i achieve this ?
I assume that author of comb sort assues same what i'm trying to do ?
If that is correct why cant divide by shrink by some int value instead of float, what is the significance ?

Comment: `gap /= shrink;`

Comment: `gap = (int)(gap/shrink+0.5)`? `(int)Math.round(gap/shrink)`?

Comment: thanks @4castle and EJP.